# Magento 2 how add product select to the widget xml?

Tags: magento2, product, widget, select

I want to add a sku product selection to the widget, but I can't find how to do it
Please tell me how can this be done

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select the single product you can reuse Magento Chooser in following way

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="..." class="...">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="id_path" xsi:type="block" visible="true" required="true" sort_order="10">
                <label translate="true">Product</label>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser">
                    <data>
                        <item name="button" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="open" xsi:type="string">Select Product...</item>
                        </item>
                    </data>
                </block>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Where `id_path` will be in format `product/$ID` or `product/$ID/$CAT_ID`

If you want to have like multiply SKUs i think [Magento 2, add sku selector to custom widget](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238941/magento-2-add-sku-selector-to-custom-widget) can help you

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did just that, but I forgot to close the question. I'll leave this here, maybe it will be useful to someone.